# Angular 2 catch observable http error in derived class

Tags: angular, typescript, exception, angular2-observables

I want to catch HTTP errors in my global exception handler.
The exception handler is working for most exceptions, but observable exceptions are not caught. The exceptions that I want to catch are HTTP exceptions.

This is how I tried sending the HTTP observable error to the exception handler.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Request, XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Http, Response, RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import { HttpException } from '../exceptions/http-exception';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Injectable()
export class HttpErrorService extends Http {

    constructor(backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
    }

    request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) {
        return super.request(url, options).catch((error: Response) => {

            // Bypass lint.
            fail();
            function fail() {
                // Here I want to throw the exception to send it to the exception handler, but it should also execute return Observable.throw(error); So I can catch the exception at the subscribe.
                throw new HttpException(error);
            }

            return Observable.throw(error);
        });
    }

}
```

This, of course, doesn't work because the code after the throw is not executed.
But the exception that is thrown is also not caught, probably because this is done in an observable.

Is there a way to catch the exception in the global exception handler, and the request is still available at `subscribe((res) => {}, (errRes) => {/*here*/})`?

Comment: what do you mean by global exception handler?

Comment: @Maximus https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler A custom ErrorHandler

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to return new observable, created from scratch:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpErrorService extends Http {

    constructor(backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
    }

    request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) {
        return Observable.create(observer => {
            super.request(url, options).subscribe(
                res => observer.next(res), //simply passing success response
                err => { //error handling
                       console.log("global error handler");
                       observer.error(err); //passing error to the method which invoked request
                },
                () => observer.complete() //passing onComplete event to the method which invoked request
             );
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to throw the exception after `observer.error(error)` and catch it successfully in the error handler.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply inject the global error handler and call [handleError](https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler#handleError) on it:

```
export class HttpErrorService extends Http {

    constructor(errorHandler: ErrorHandler, backend: XHRBackend...) {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
    }

    request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) {
        return super.request(url, options).catch((error: Response) => {

            // Bypass lint.
            fail();
            function fail() {
                // Here I want to throw the exception...
                const error = new HttpException(error);
                errorHandler.handleError(error); //<----------------- here!
            }

            return Observable.throw(error);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Injecting the error handler is not working because there are dependency injection parameters in the constructor.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean? and can you post your solution?

Comment: I think that @JanWytze want to keep same list of constructor parameters, as in Http, to avoid using factory in module.

Comment: @MaciejTreder, yeah, right, thanks. They use their custom HTTP service instead of default I guess, correct?

Comment: @Maximus I don't know. I guess so too ;)

Comment: @MaciejTreder, yeah, that's so annoying to guess... In that case your solution is correct, this is how it's done [in the sources](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/http/src/backends/xhr_backend.ts#L107). Upvoted)

Comment: @Maximus Thanks :)